# Error message in Treeclim

Tags: r

I'm attempting to use the package treeclim to analyze my tree ring growth data and climate. I measured the widths in CooRecorder, grouped them into series in CDENDRO, and read them into R-Studio using dplR read.rwl function. However, I keep getting an error message reading

> "Error in dcc(Plot92.crn, Site92PRISM, selection = -6:9, method = "response",  : 
>     Overlapping time span of chrono and climate records is smaller than number of parameters! Consider adapting the number of parameters to a maximum of 100."

I have 100 years of monthly climate data that looks like below:

```
# head(Site92PRISM)
  year month  ppt tmax tmin tmean vpdmin..hPa. vpdmax..hPa. site
1 1915    01 0.97 26.1 12.3  19.2         0.97         2.32   92
2 1915    02 1.20 31.5 16.2  23.9         1.03         3.30   92
3 1915    03 2.51 36.0 17.0  26.5         0.97         4.69   92
4 1915    04 3.45 48.9 26.3  37.6         1.14         8.13   92
5 1915    05 3.95 44.6 29.1  36.9         0.94         5.58   92
6 1915    06 6.64 51.0 31.5  41.3         1.04         7.93   92
```

And my chronology, made in dplR looks like below:

```
#head(Plot92.crn)
        CAMstd samp.depth
1840 0.7180693          1
1841 0.3175528          1
1842 0.5729651          1
1843 0.9785082          1
1844 0.7676334          1
1845 0.3633687          1
```

Where am I going wrong? Both files contain data from 1915-2015.

Comment: Including a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in your question will increase your chances of getting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I posted a similar question to the author in the google forum of the package (i.e. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/treeclim).

What you need to make sure of is that the number of parameters (`n_param`) is less or equal to the sample size of your dendrochronological data. By 'number of parameters' I mean the total number of columns in the climatic variables matrices.

For instance, in the following analysis:

```
resp <- dcc(chrono = my_chrono,
            climate = list(precip, temp),
            boot = 'stationary')
```

You need to make sure that the following is `TRUE` :

```
length(unique(rownames(my_chrono))) >= (ncol(precip)-1) + (ncol(temp)-1)
```

`ncol(precip)-1` and not `ncol(precip)` because the first column of the matrix is `YEAR`. Also note that in my example the years in `my_chrono` are the same years as in `precip` and `temp`, which doesn't have to be the case to run the function (it will automatically take the common years).

Finally, if the previous line code gives you `FALSE`, you can reduce the number of parameters with the argument `selection` like this :

```
resp <- dcc(chrono = my_chrono,
            climate = list(precip, temp),
            selection = .range(6:12,'prec') + .range(6:12, 'temp'),
            var_names = c('prec', 'temp'),
            boot = 'stationary')
```

Because the `dcc` function automatically takes all months from previous June to current September (i.e. `.range(-6:9)`), you may need to reduce that range.